# Освобождение занятой памяти оператором new

Tags: c++

Вот, к примеру, у меня есть такой код:

```
Type *Obj = nullptr;
Obj = new Type;
Obj = new Type;
delete Obj;
```

Будет ли достаточно использовать один оператор `delete` в конце? Считается ли первая выделенная память свободной после второго `new` ?

Comment: Не используйте сырые указатели. Для таких задач есть `std::unique_ptr`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Имеете утечку памяти в размере одного `Type`.

При присваивании нового значения указателю старое автоматически не освобождается. Да это было бы и странно - представьте

```
Type *Obj = nullptr, *Copy = nullptr;
Obj = new Type;
Copy = Obj;
Obj = new Type;
delete Obj;
```

Если бы было, как вы полагаете - после этого `Copy` указывал бы на невалидную память, так что работать с копиями указателей было бы решительно невозможно...

Comment: Вопрос скорее всего основан на предположении о существовании в С++ какого-то встроенного механизма garbage collection (reference counting или что-то в этом роде). В рамках такого предположения пример с `Copy = Obj` непоказателен. Спрашивающий логично предположит, что существование `Copy` "спасает" объект от уничтожения.

Comment: @AnT Да, о таком варианте я не подумал...

Comment: @AnT Ан нет, понял, почему не подумал - в таком случае `delete` был бы не нужен, достаточно было бы обнуления `Obj`. Тут уж, как говорится, или крестик сними, или трусы одень...